# Gradle get what repository a dependency was resolved from (smart fat jar)

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a use case where I need to create a *smart* fat jar. What, exactly does that mean?

Essentially I have different repositories which our application dependencies can be resolved from, some of them exist in a globally replicated file share (which is served as an ivy repository), while others exist in a private maven repository that is not productionized, and should not be used directly by applications in production.

I would like to create a **fat jar** in a smart way, such that:

- If the dependency came from the private maven repository, it should be added to the fat jar.
- If the dependency came from the file share, it points to the jar'directly in that file share (i.e. that fat jar's manifest adds that jar to the classpath.

**Do any facilities exist for me to be able to distinguish where a dependency is resolved from?**

For example:

```
repositories {
   stableIvy()
   unreliableMaven()   
}

dependencies {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Gradle 5.2 there is no API that allows you to acces that information. However this is internally known by Gradle. You could file a feature request against the project.

Comment: How about being logged or printed somewhere ?